# Facebook connect integration

Tags: facebook

I want users to able to sign up in my application(rails) using facebook connect.
However I am not very sure what all information of the user will be available ,specifically the email of the user. I know that the emails of the user's friends are not available, but not sure if the email of the user himself is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can prompt the user for `email` [extended permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).